# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqLServer.SMO

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

We have a `VB application` that downloads databases from `SQL Server 2005`.

We migrated the `SQL server version to 2016`.

The application has stopped working.

(I was told that we need to install a newer version of the SMO connection libraries on our workstations to connect to the SQL server, so we will have to recompile / test / modify our code with SQL Server 2016 compatible libraries. .)

I installed the following 3 files:

```
AMO objects (SQL_AS_AMO.msi)SMO Objects (SharedManagementObjects.msi)
SQL CLR Types (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)
```

From: https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/219401687-SQL-Analysis-Management-Objects

But I do not know what to do next. What should be changed in the source code of the application? how to call these libraries in my application?

Help me please, I'm bad at VB

> Error :
>
> could not load file or assembly MicrosoftSQLserver.SMO,
>   Version=9.0.242.0 Cuture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you checked the referenced in the project ot make sure they reference the new versions? And that it builds properly now?

Comment: Why are you getting the updated files from a 3rd party instead of MS?  see: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) for installer and [Backward Compatibility in SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/backward-compatibility-in-smo?view=sql-server-2016) and the related articles for more information.

Comment: Hello i've check all references and install it from microsoft, but now when i run the project i have this error : 
(http://prod5-pow-enquetes.integra.fr/09327/ObjectInstance.png)      

i have this error message when i click to launch treatment

Comment: No one wants to help me ? o O